# Ipad/Iphone designing in Full-Screen vs Non-Full-Screen?

Tags: mobile, iphone, ios, ipad, fullscreen

I've noticed that most games are in full screen mode and some Apps have taken this on in design.  Is there any research or argument for having an App in Full-Screen vs Non-Full-Screen?

The only difference is the top bar, which displays the service provider, time, and battery life of your device.  If, the issue is allowing the user to see what time it is, would it be bad to go full-screen and have a stylized clock up top matching the App's design, instead of being in a Non-Full-Screen mode?

Does anyone have additional research around this?

Comment: In iOS, the top bar can also be dragged down, revealing the updates center. This allows the user to keep checking out updates, while pausing from the app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Apple's iOS guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41) say to *"Think twice before hiding the status bar if your app is not a game or full-screen media-viewing app."*  I think their attitude is that if you don't really need the extra space, leave the status bar visible so people can see the time and battery life.  Also, from same link above, *"don't create a custom status bar."*

Answer (score 0):

Depends completely on the usage of that app. If the user needs to look at the status bar constantly then it probably wouldn't be the best idea (I would remove the status bar only for game applications).

How to hide the Status bar:

```
 - In XCode, go to your project folder > supporting files > [project
   name]-Info.plist
 - Hover to the last line and click the “+” button to add another entry.
 - Enter the key field as “UIStatusBarHidden”. Once you’ve done that, it
   will change to “Status Bar is Initially Hidden”.
 - Enter the value field as “YES”.
```